# Array contents are not displaying properly

Tags: c, arrays, input, output

C beginner here, I have a program that I'm working on and unfortunately the program is either not properly reading in the array or it's not displaying the contents properly.

Here's what I have

```
int main()
{
    int size;     // the number of elements 

    printf("Enter size of the array: \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    double *array = malloc(size*sizeof(int));  //memory allocated using malloc
    if (array == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Enter elements of array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("Results:");

    double min = array[0]; 
    printf("\nmin = %.3lf ", min);
    double max = array[size - 1]; 
    printf("\nmax = %.3lf", max);
```

and here's my output

[image]

Comment: You are allocating an array of integers and assigning it to a double pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> double *array = malloc(size*sizeof(int));

should be:

```
double *array = malloc( size * sizeof(double) );
```

> scanf("%d", &array[i]);

and here wrong control string, should be `%lf` for double, not `%d`

Comment: Did it, same things still happening